# I used the train and test set in the SARIMA to predict the supposed to be current value, but how am i going to predict the value beyond my timestamp

Tags: pandas, numpy, dataframe, arima

I already successfully build SARIMA model based on my data set. My question here is how am I going to predict the future value which are beyond my data set(in timestamp). Any suggestion ?

Here is my SARIMA model that i able to make with graph.[SARIMA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NrSCt.png). The blue is on current, red is forecasted.

Here is my training and test set look like. [Training Set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ERcgw.png). [Test Set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mG0yq.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can use 
`forecast=model.forecast(steps=number of steps to go in future)`

This will return forecasts along with standard error for given confidence interval.
From that, you can access forecasts like `forecast[0]`.

Reference: http://www.statsmodels.org/stable/generated/statsmodels.tsa.arima_model.ARIMAResults.forecast.html